# Unknown data format `function`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

Either I have an embarrassing typo or the latest release of tikz has a bug.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization[school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
    data [format=function] {
      var x: interval [-10:10], samples 50;
      func y = sin(\value x)/\value x;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I checked the tikz source, so a definition exists, but is either not being loaded or has a bad catcode.

Comment: Any reason for this question to be tagged `{vi}` ? You must have meant `visualisation` or something ?

Comment: @marsupilam - I have no ideal how the vi tag got there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works, sort of.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization[school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
    data[format=function] {
      var x : interval [-10:10] samples 50;
      func y = sin(\value x) / \value x;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Embarrassing typo (datavisualization.formats.functions) it is!

Comment: Also, no comma before samples, I think.  And you don't want to divide by zero.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid x=0 by using an even number of samples.

Comment: Actually, my biggest mistake was forgetting to convert to degrees with deg(\value x).

Comment: Glad it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, the final solution was to use pgfplots instead.  The `school book axes` uses the same scale for x and y.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, ymax=1.1, clip=false]
\addplot[domain=-10:10 ,samples=50, smooth] {sin(deg(x))/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,name=border, ymax=1.01, smooth]
\addplot[domain=-.5:.5 ,samples=20] {sin(deg(x))/x};
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs: -0.2,.99);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs: 0.2,1.01);
\end{axis}
\draw[blue] (border.west |- A) -- (border.east |- A) node[right] {$b-\epsilon$};
\draw[blue] (border.west |- B) -- (border.east |- B) node[right] {$b+\epsilon$};
\draw[red] (border.south -| A) -- (border.north -| A) node[above left] {$a-\upsilon$};
\draw[red] (border.south -| B) -- (border.north -| B) node[above right] {$a+\upsilon$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]